# Python File Integrity Monitoring

Tags: python, file, hash, for-loop, md5

I have written the following code and can't get it working and I can't see why.  The code:

1. Reads list of target files
2. Loops through the directories
3. Runs MD5 hash on the file
4. Checks the activefile for previous md5 hashes for said file
5. If the file is new it will log it as new
6. If the log is existing but changed it will write the change and log the change
7. If not new and no change then do nothing

Here is the code:

```
import hashlib
import logging as log
import optparse
import os
import re
import sys
import glob
import shutil

def md5(fileName):
    """Compute md5 hash of the specified file"""
    try:
        fileHandle = open(fileName, "rb")
    except IOError:
        return
    m5Hash = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        data = fileHandle.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        m5Hash.update(data)
    fileHandle.close()
    return m5Hash.hexdigest()

req = open("requested.txt")
for reqline in req:
    reqName = reqline[reqline.rfind('/') + 1:len(reqline) - 1]
    reqDir = reqline[0:reqline.rfind('/') + 1] 
    tempFile = open("activetemp.txt", 'w') 
    for name in glob.glob(reqDir + reqName):    
        fileHash = md5(name) 
        actInt = 0
        if fileHash != None:

            actFile = open("activefile.txt")

            for actLine in actFile:
                actNameDir = actLine[0:actLine.rfind(' : ')]
                actHash = actLine[actLine.rfind(' : ') + 3:len(actLine) -1]
                if actNameDir == name and actHash == fileHash:
                    tempFile.write(name + " : " + fileHash + "\n")
                    actInt = 1 
                    print fileHash
                    print actHash
                    print name
                    print actNameDir
                if actNameDir == name and actHash != fileHash:
                    fimlog = open("fimlog.txt", 'a')
                    tempFile.write(name + " : " + actHash + "\n")         
                    actInt = 1
                    fimlog.write("FIM Log: The file " + name +  " was modified: " + actHash + "\n") 
            if actInt == 0: 
                fimlog = open("fimlog.txt", 'a')
                fimlog.write("FIM Log: The file " + name +  " was created: " + fileHash + "\n")
                tempFile.write(name + " : " + fileHash + "\n")                       

shutil.copyfile("activetemp.txt", "activefile.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

You never really described the problem, but one possible culprit is that you never close the tempFile (or the other files for that matter), so the file copy at the end may fail.

Comment: The problem is that some files do not ever get written to the activefile and some do.  The first 50 or so do not get written to activefile and I can't see why.